# Snippets in Kwrite

Tags: code-snippets, kde-plasma

Kwrite (KDE editor) provides very handy and useful functionality. But, I could not figure out how to insert code snippets in Kwrite. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the definition of a "code-snippet"?

Comment: snippet is like a short cut for e.g. instead of writing names og all header files in c, i could use some shortcut to save manual efforts

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use kate instead.

Comment: This barely qualifies as an answer.  At least provide a link to such.

Comment: The person who knows what a kwrite editor is, should know also about kate. kwrite doesn't have implemented access to katepart plugins - it is just simplified version of editor in KDE. And kate has such plugins including snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. If you are defining snippets you won't be able to use them until you close the current document and re-open it.
Hope that helps.